# EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE for SpeechRecognizer?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Forcing a particular language for RecognizerIntent is straightforward as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10548680/679180).

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en-US");
```

But that only works if the `intent` instantiated is of type [RecognizerIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html).

In my application I use the lower-level `SpeechRecognizer`, i.e.:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
```

And trying to force the language as decribed above simply doesn't work.

What is the proper way of programmatically setting the language preference for [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html)?

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language preference should work.

Please post more of you code.

You should still create an `Intent` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
```

NOT like this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
```

Then you have to call the `SpeechRecognizer` class directly.

Are you doing that?

For reference, see this [code](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/SpeechRecognizingActivity.java)'s `recognizeSpeechDirectly()` method.