# How to get a list of languages supported by the Speech Recognition API on Android?

Tags: android, speech-to-text, android-speech-api

I found this on stackoverflow: [How to set the language in speech recognition on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538791/how-to-set-the-language-in-speech-recognition-on-android) . The top answer explains how to do so programmatically by broadcasting an intent with the list of languages to a new activity and you can store that list in a Bundle object. But how do you retrieve the list of languages from the Bundle object?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) is all you need. And isn't that `getStringArrayList` call from the other post what you want?

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538791/how-to-set-the-language-in-speech-recognition-on-android) post. As it mentioned,

> your app can query for the list of supported languages by sending a RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS ordered broadcast

Answer (score 0):

If you use Speech Recognition API on Android for Google then check [this](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages).