# Speech recognition - only English, not any other lanugage

Tags: android, kotlin, speech

I want to recognize only English with Kotlin Android.
But my phone uses the Korean language setting.

My app returns Korean first. But I want only English text.
Please help me.  Below is my code:

```
val rintent = Intent( RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        rintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE , Locale.US)
        rintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, Locale.US);
        rintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE , true )
        rintent.putExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL , RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM )
        rintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS , 3 )
```

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538791/how-to-set-the-language-in-speech-recognition-on-android

Comment: Thank you . Locale.US . not work.  Locale.US.toString() works